# Change iTerm2 window and tab titles in zsh

Tags: command-line, osx-snow-leopard, zsh, iterm

I want to label the window tabs of terminal sessions. I'm using the zshell in iterm2 on OSX. Is it possible to change the label of a window tab dynamically in the terminal?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can enter the following in `zsh` to set the window title of iTerm2:

```
echo -ne "\e]1;this is the title\a"
```

If you want to automate that to insert e.g. the current time or working directory, edit your `zsh` configuration files to set the title in the `precmd()` function to e.g. `$PWD`.

```
echo -ne "\e]1;$PWD\a"
```

You can read about the `precmd` function in `man zshmisc` in the section `SPECIAL FUNCTIONS`.

[image]

Comment: when I execute the command echo -ne "\e]1;this is the title\a" the tab title does not change. Is there a setting I have to change in iterm2?

Comment: Figured it out. I have to deselect all the options for window and tab titles in the iterm->preferences->appearance section. and in the .zshrc I have to uncomment/add export DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

Thanks @Daniel Beck

Comment: You also need to set `Profiles > Terminal > Terminal Emulation > Terminal may set tab/window title`.

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK (for me, at least) IN THE LATEST VERSION OF iTerm (3.3.0)

Comment: And doesn't work for me on latest stable version of `iTerm2` (3.2.9)

Comment: Check my answer. I had the same issue and fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in iTerm2 3.3.10, even when doing what @NunoGonçalves wrote.

Comment: That’s weird; it works for me in iTerm2 3.3.12.

Comment: I had to do `prompt_pure_set_title() true # disables pure setting the title`. Your own theme might have sth similar.

Answer (score 57):

What works for me:

```
echo -e "\033];this is the title\007"
```

If you use Mac OSX and iTerm, iTerm2::

- iTerm → Preferences → Appearance → Window & Tab Titles → uncheck all

If you use Oh My Zsh, then you may need to edit your settings. Your settings are typically in the file `~/.zshrc`. You want to add or edit your settings to make sure this line exists:

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

Comment: It still works as of 02/28/2018.

Comment: `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE` is an Oh My Zsh feature, not zsh

Comment: i'm using Oh My Zsh, and the DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE fixed it for me.

Answer (score 45):

One of the amenities of using iTerm is the possibility of setting window title & tab title separately:
[image: example of using tab & window title separately]

```
# $1 = type; 0 - both, 1 - tab, 2 - title
# rest = text
setTerminalText () {
    # echo works in bash & zsh
    local mode=$1 ; shift
    echo -ne "\033]$mode;$@\007"
}
stt_both  () { setTerminalText 0 $@; }
stt_tab   () { setTerminalText 1 $@; }
stt_title () { setTerminalText 2 $@; }
```

This way you can immediately see what host you're connected to in what window, and the window title for each tab shows user & CWD.

Comment: I just noticed that the Terminal.app version in OS X Lion supports this as well.

Comment: silly question:  you add these code to `.bashrc`, right?

Comment: Also appears that (in iTerm2 Build 1.0.0.20140629) until you change the Window Title... it tracks the tab title, no matter what. I'm sure that's a setting. Once the Window title is changed (2) it no longer tracks tab title.

Comment: I modified the function above to include the line `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` that fixed the issue and this way if I don't set the title, I still get the automatic title feature

Answer (score 5):

A `precmd` does the trick. However, some oh-my-zsh themes mess around with the window title. Set `PR_TITLEBAR` to an empty string to fix it.

```
set-window-title() {
  # /Users/clessg/projects/dotfiles -> ~/p/dotfiles
  window_title="\e]0;${${PWD/#"$HOME"/~}/projects/p}\a"
  echo -ne "$window_title"
}

PR_TITLEBAR=''
set-window-title
add-zsh-hook precmd set-window-title
```

I would also recommend playing around with the tab settings of iTerm2 in Preferences -> Appearance.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers seemed to work for me, probably for the iterm2 version (3.3.3).

I found this out: 
https://gist.github.com/phette23/5270658#gistcomment-3020766

Essentially, you can do whatever is said in all other answers, but also need to set 
`Preferences > Profiles > General > Title -> Name (Job)`

This worked for me.

Comment: This isn't under the `General` tab, it's under the `Profiles` tab

Comment: Right. I missed the `> Profiles` one. My bad. Updated.

Comment: there isn't `Name (Job)` as an option now.

Comment: But there is Job Name...

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer has worked for me for a long time but is now broken in the latest version of iTerm2.  A workaround I found was to enable the Python API and create a script which sets the tab name like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import argparse

import iterm2

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Set the tab name')
    parser.add_argument('name')
    return parser.parse_args()

ARGS = get_args()

async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    window = app.current_terminal_window
    if window is not None:
        tab = window.current_tab
        await tab.async_set_title(ARGS.name)
    else:
        # You can view this message in the script console.
        print("No current window")

iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

Saved as "tab_name.py", then invoked with:

```
~/Library/ApplicationSupport/iTerm2/iterm2env/versions/*/bin/python3 ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/iTerm2/Scripts/tab_name.py "new tab name"
```

It's not nearly as nice or elegant as the accepted answer, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check
Profile -> {yourProfile} -> General -> "Application in terminal may change the title"

If you don't do this, your session name will be locked unless you unlock manually.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$PWD\007"'` into `~/.bash_profile` worked for me.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90737/49605

Comment: The question specifically says zsh, not bash.

Comment: Good, it works in bash!

Answer (score -2):

iTerm -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Window & Tab titles -> check Show profile name option

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people ask. Part of writing a good answer is providing context for the proposed solution. Please edit your answer and explain why your solution works, and what, *specifically*, it does.