# Set Tab Title to your current working directory instead of the current job name in zsh iterms

Tags: zsh, iterm

I'm running iTerms on my Mac OS X with `zsh`. With my workflow I have to switch between tab a lot and sometime I have to spend too much time just to find which tab is the one I'm looking for because all of them having the same name.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above. Now that would be very useful for me to at least display the `Tab` `Title` to the current working directory instead of the `Job name` in iTerms for `zsh`

I have looked at the preferences and there is no option for that. It will only display the `CWD` when the job is not running but once it is running then the job name will be display instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change iTerm2 window and tab titles in zsh](http://superuser.com/questions/292652/change-iterm2-window-and-tab-titles-in-zsh)

Comment: @mpy well that is not really answered my question because when the process is running the name is changed again.

Comment: You are right, it does not answer exactly your question. But I was thinking of it as a duplicate, because in the linked answers you get (a.) the escape sequences how to set tab and window title and (b.) the hint about `precmd`. But I must admit, that in your case it could also be the function `preexec` which changes your title -- I retracted my close vote.

Comment: Thanks. I will do some research on how to do that because it is very annoying not to know which tab is which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the hook functions `precmd` and `preexec` with `which precmd` and `which preexec`, resp.:

> **precmd**   Executed before each prompt. (...)
>
> **preexec**    Executed  just  after a command has been read and is about to be
>                 executed.  (...) The  actual  command  that will be executed (including
>                 expanded aliases) is passed in two different forms:  the  second
>                 argument  is  a single-line, size-limited version of the command
>                 (with things like function bodies elided);  the  third  argument
>                 contains the full text that is being executed.

Probably in `preexec` there is some code which changes the tab title to `$2` or `$3`.

As a first test you can disable both hook functions completely (`precmd() {}`, `preexec() {}`), set the title manually (`echo -ne "\e]1;TEST\a"`) and check if it remains if you execute a command.

Then try to find the source of the original setting, either in you personal RC files (`~/.zshrc`) or the system wide ones (`/etc/zsh*`).

If sucessful, you can think about a sensible tab title and put the `echo` command to `precmd` like suggested by @Tiago.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your zsh configuration files to set the title in the [precmd()](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions) function to e.g. `$PWD`.

```
echo -ne "\e]1;$PWD\a"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that right, but getting the present working directory overwrite the current job is that the way you do it?