# What is the text in the frame header of Terminal on startup?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

When I start up a Terminal window on macOS, the following text scrolls by in the frame header:

[image: terminal init]

I recognize a few of my `brew`'d packages like `pyenv` in there, as well as some basic posix packages, but I'm not sure of where its all coming from.

Comment: Those are Zsh or Bash items that load when you start up a terminal. Check `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` to see  what corresponds to what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [someone said in the comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1824678/what-is-the-text-in-the-frame-header-of-terminal-on-startup#comment2873751_1824678), they are the programs being run by your startup scripts. You can also control what the terminal title is using:

```bash
# Set terminal window and tab/icon title
#
# usage: title short_tab_title [long_window_title]
#
# See: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#ss3.1
# Fully supports screen, iterm, and probably most modern xterm and rxvt
# (In screen, only short_tab_title is used)
# Limited support for Apple Terminal (Terminal can't set window and tab separately)
function title {
    # forked from OMZ, see https://superuser.com/a/344397/856545 for setting tab and window separately
    emulate -L zsh
    setopt prompt_subst

    {
        [[ "$EMACS" == *term* ]] && return

        # if $2 is unset use $1 as default
        # if it is set and empty, leave it as is
        : ${2=$1}

        case "$TERM" in
            cygwin|xterm*|putty*|rxvt*|ansi)
                print -Pn "\e]2;$2:q\a" # set window name
                print -Pn "\e]1;$1:q\a" # set tab name
                ;;
            screen*)
                print -Pn "\ek$1:q\e\\" # set screen hardstatus
                ;;
            *)
                if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "iTerm.app" ]]; then
                    print -Pn "\e]2;$2:q\a" # set window name
                    print -Pn "\e]1;$1:q\a" # set tab name
                else
                    # Try to use terminfo to set the title
                    # If the feature is available set title
                    if [[ -n "$terminfo[fsl]" ]] && [[ -n "$terminfo[tsl]" ]]; then
                        echoti tsl
                        print -Pn "$1"
                        echoti fsl
                    fi
                fi
                ;;
        esac
    } >/dev/tty
}
```